# Error message for tel: url scheme

Tags: android, html

I am using:

```html
<li><a class= "call-us" href= "tel:+1-239-555-1212">239-555-1212</a></li>
```

I am receiving the error message "net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME" When testing website on Android.
This works with the iphone, but fails every time on Android 5.0.2 (HTC One M8)  This is not the actual number, but the results are the same.  I have tried this with and without the plus sign, with and without the hyphens. Does anyone have any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you omit the '+' in your link?

Comment: Tried it, still does not work.  Beginning to wonder if its just my phone (HTC one).  But I have no other devices to test it on.